# unable to install laravel dusk dashboard

Tags: installation, dependencies, dashboard, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

i am trying to install dusk dashborad by this command:

> composer require beyondcode/dusk-dashboard --dev

- but unable to install
  when tried to install, it gives the error for "guzzlehttp/guzzle" version.

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires beyondcode/dusk-dashboard ^2.0 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/dusk-dashboard[2.0.0].
> - beyondcode/dusk-dashboard 2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.0).
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
> downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific
> versions.

tried downgrading to guzzlehttp/guzzle to ^6.3 but then it gives this error:

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires beyondcode/dusk-dashboard ^2.0 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/dusk-dashboard[2.0.0].
> - beyondcode/dusk-dashboard 2.0.0 requires illuminate/console 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|6.*|7.* -> found illuminate/console[v5.6.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> but after installing the correct version asked in the error which is ^6.3 ,it gives this error:

i also tried updating option --wtin-all-depandencies. but did not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the maintainer is not actively maintaining the package. The last commit was  May 30, 2020, to make it compatible with Laravel 7.